# Using an interceptor exported from a module using module service

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I created an Interceptor with a related module so that I could manage its `imports` without having to import them into the `AppModule`.

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
        const env = configService.getOrThrow('NECESSARY_ENV');

        // do stuff...
    }

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigModule} from '@nestjs/config';
import {
    RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor
} from '@app/interceptor-request-response-logger/request-response-logger.interceptor';
import envConfig from '@app/interceptor-request-response-logger/config/env.config';

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(envConfig)],
    providers: [RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor],
    exports: [RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor]
})
export class RequestResponseLoggerModule {
}
```

I also had to add the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` imports in `AppModule` otherwise the `ConfigModule.forFeatures(...)` in the `RequestResponseLoggerModule` would not work.

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {SearchController} from './controllers/search.controller';
import {SearchService} from './services/search.service';
import {RequestResponseLoggerModule} from '@app/interceptor-request-response-logger';
import {ConfigModule} from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot(),
        RequestResponseLoggerModule
    ],
    controllers: [SearchController],
    providers: [
        SearchService
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Before I get into some abyss trying to get something unintended to work I would like to ask if it makes sense to have such an approach or if Interceptors inherit the module and thus the Module imports into which they are imported.

The project I'm working on will have a lot of these Interceptors that I'll need to reuse on various apps, and that's why I'm trying to figure out how to start with the design of my codebase correctly.

Comment: just ran into this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than providing and exporting the interceptor, the module can import and export whatever modules it needs to, as well as provide and export whatever providers the interceptor depends on. Interceptors are a special psuedo-provider referred to as "enhancers", that follow *most* but not all of the rules that regular providers do. Other enhancers include guards, pipes, and filters, just as an fyi.

Enhancers cannot be provided through the `providers` array **unless** you plan to use the `APP_INTERCEPTOR` provider and use the [`useExisting` custom provider option](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#alias-providers-useexisting).

So, in your case, it looks like your `RequestResponseLoggerModule` should look like

```js
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigModule} from '@nestjs/config';
import envConfig from '@app/interceptor-request-response-logger/config/env.config';

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(envConfig)],
    providers: [],
    exports: [ConfigModule]
})
export class RequestResponseLoggerModule {
}
```

And now, in whatever modules you want to use the `RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor` you can import the `RequestResponseLoggerModule` and `@UseInterceptor(RequestResponseLoggerInterceptor)` with all of its config in place and ready to be made use of.